# Not Found / Forbidden error while using GET Operation in AWS S3 folder

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest

I'm trying to get a csv file from a AWS s3 bucket, I've access to bucket and some of the folders in it. But i'm unable to access("GET") files from one of the folder.
I get an error `NOT FOUND"/404` when I try to access the folder, when I specify the file name in folder I get a different error `Forbidden/403`.

Below is the snippet of my code

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:AWS_S3');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getStatus());
System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: What other headers are you setting in postman? Are you doing the same in apex?

Comment: No, actually i'm testing the access to each folders in bucket from Anonymous Window and found this issue for a particular folder.

Comment: Seems like you're using Named Credentials therefore you're really not showing the endpoint you're trying to connect (seems like you're missing the path)

Comment: Checked the path,  well it's working for other folders under the same bucket, but throws a response "Not Found" for this particular one. Tried changing the bucket policy too but no luck.